# Custom Table Mapping with Sequel gem

Tags: ruby, sequel, sequel-gem

Been spinning my wheels. How would one specify a custom table mapping with the sequel gem?

I've done the following

init.rb

```
OTHER_DB = Sequel.connect(:adapter => 'tinytds', :host => 'host1', :database => 'mydatabase', :user => 'myuser', :password => 'mypassword')

Namespace::MyModel.db = OTHER_DB
```

MyModel.rb

```
module Namespace
  class MyModel < Sequel::Model('myschema.MyModelTable')
  end
end
```

It complains about the  'myschema.MyModelTable' in the constructor. I've also tried set_dataset('myschema.MyModelTable') with no success.

The docs seem to be a bit opaque on how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this with the following code

```
module Namespace
  class MyModel < Sequel::Model(Sequel.qualify(:myschema,:MyModelTable))
  end
end
```

More examples can be found in the tests [here](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/spec/model/model_spec.rb#L22-L48)

Comment: GREAT!. This example solve me a lot of problems!!. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
class MyModel < Sequel::Model(:myschema__MyModelTable)
end
```

there are two underscores.  that's the convention Sequel's tinytds adapter uses to specify a schema.  see line 194: https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/lib/sequel/adapters/tinytds.rb